# How does one install and test Windows locales in support of `set locale()` in the GitHub Windows runner?

Tags: windows, perl, posix, locale, setlocale

I've [added tests for localization to Sqitch](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/pull/808), which requires that the POSIX `setlocale()` function return an appropriate value. A couple of GitHub workflows run this tests on Linux, macOS, and Windows, and work fine. On Linux, the workflow has to install the locales for the tests to pass:

```yaml
- if: runner.os == 'Linux'
  name: Install Apt Packages
  run: sudo apt-get install -qq language-pack-fr language-pack-en language-pack-de language-pack-it
```

The tests, however, [fail on Windows](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/actions/runs/7391021799/job/20107078850). The warning emitted when it tries to set the locale to `en-US.UTF-8` is:

```
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LC_ALL = "en-US.UTF-8",
    (possibly more locale environment variables)
    LANG = (unset)
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the system default locale ("English_United States.1252").
```

I suspect that this error is not a Perl issue, since Perl, IIUC, delegates to the [Windows `setlocale` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale), which explicitly documents support for the `LC_ALL` environment variable and [the `en-US.UTF-8` format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=msvc-170#utf-8-support).

I had similar issues on Linux till I figured out how to `apt-get install` the locales, and suspect a lack of localization libraries on the GitHub Windows runner. I tried to install them with this incantation:

```yaml
- if: runner.os == 'Windows'
  name: Install Language Packs
  run: |
    Install-Language -Language en-US
    Install-Language -Language fr-FR
    Install-Language -Language de-DE
    Install-Language -Language it-IT
```

But [the build](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/actions/runs/7372458415/job/20060804402) fails with

```
The term 'Install-Language' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable
```

I assume this is because [`Install-Language`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/languagepackmanagement/install-language?view=windowsserver2022-ps) requires admin access.

So, how does one install localization languages on the GitHub Windows runner? The goal is for a workflow like this:

```yaml
name: Test setlocale
on: [push]
jobs:
  test:
    name: Test setlocale
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: shogo82148/actions-setup-perl@v1
        with: { perl-version: latest }
      - run: Install-Language -Language fr-FR
      - run: perl -MPOSIX -E "say POSIX::setlocale(POSIX::LC_ALL)"
        env: { LC_ALL: fr_FR.UTF-8 }
```

to emit `fr_FR.UTF-8`.

I also put together [this simple test case](https://github.com/theory/test-perl-action/blob/setlocale/.github/workflows/test.yml), which [currently fails](https://github.com/theory/test-perl-action/actions/runs/7440715506/job/20242033340).

Comment: Related unanswered [GitHub community question](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/68929)

Comment: *"I tried to install them with this incantation ... Install-Language -Language en-US "* Can you provide a link to the complete GitHub action workflow you used, then we can try to reproduce..

Comment: Yes, here's the [`os.yml` as of that failed build](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/blob/13e8ac4310d9ea3ad0f8f05347dfe64f0fe7b365/.github/workflows/os.yml).

Comment: Also added a simple workflow to the question.

Comment: *"The goal is for a workflow like this ... to emit French_France.1252"* : According to this page https://docs.moodle.org/403/en/Table_of_locales you would need to set LC_ALL to `French_France.1252` instead of `fr_FR.UTF-8`

Comment: Okay. I updated the test script to try `English_United States.UTF-8` and [it failed](https://github.com/theory/test-perl-action/actions/runs/7440872249/job/20242348332), too, seems to only support 1252. That's frustrating, as Sqitch always and only emits UTF-8.

Comment: [1252 does work](https://github.com/theory/test-perl-action/actions/runs/7440880895/job/20242367983), so that's good. But [the docs clearly mention UTF-8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=msvc-170#utf-8-support), which is consternating. It even says that `en_us.utf8` is legit.

Comment: *"..as Sqitch always and only emits UTF-8"* : But Perl does work internally with UTF-8, so then it's just a question of decoding input to the perl script? The other locale formatting can be done with the 1252 locales?

Comment: The problem is that Locale::TextDomain uses `gettext` to determine the locale to use, and when it's set to `French_France.1252`, it doesn't find the [`fr_FR` translations](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/blob/v1.4.0/po/fr_FR.po). I'm about to give up on localization on Windows, it's maddening.

Comment: *"The problem is that Locale::TextDomain uses gettext to determine the locale to use..."* Maybe you could create a minimal example with Locale::TextDomain? Then we can try reproduce..

Comment: Oh man, [this might be the problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11153468).

Comment: Okay, [Locale::TextDomain example](https://github.com/theory/test-perl-action/blob/locales/t/locale-textdomain.t) that [fails](https://github.com/theory/test-perl-action/actions/runs/7441954438/job/20244760543) on [French_France.1252](https://github.com/theory/test-perl-action/blob/057c04a21a46dc8d11c4d96b07da5f2020cff975/.github/workflows/test.yml#L32-L34). Note that it relies on the compiled gettext dictionaries [in lib/LocalData](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch/pull/808/files#diff-03e7af36cdcace6a528391bc6a04ca6c205ba59b59e80417f2af9b0c56bf7a04) (copied from the Sqitch tests).

Comment: From [various comments in its source](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Agflohr%2Flibintl-perl%20windows&type=code), it does seem like Locale::TextDomain/gettext have som challenges on Windows.

Comment: From the Perl monks thread: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11153468 it seems like you need a Perl build with the UCRT runtime? See also  https://github.com/StrawberryPerl/Perl-Dist-Strawberry/issues/152

Comment: Interesting. That [does seem to be the solution](https://github.com/StrawberryPerl/Perl-Dist-Strawberry/issues/150#issuecomment-1784955524). I opened [this issue](https://github.com/shogo82148/actions-setup-perl/issues/1713) to request it for the Perl action.